# Conditional while loop to calculate cumulative sum?

Tags: python, while-loop, cumulative-sum

I want to write a function that takes a list of numbers and returns the cumulative sum; that is, a new list where the ith element is the sum of the first i+1 elements from the original list. For example, the cumulative sum of `[1, 2, 3]` is `[1, 3, 6]`.

Here is my code so far:

```
 def count(list1):
     x = 0
     total = 0
     while x < len(list1):
         if x == 0:
             total = list1[0]
             print total
             x = x +1
         else:
             total = list1[x] + list1[x -1]
             print total
             x = x + 1
     return total 

print count([1, 2, 3, 4, 7])
```

However, it is not working.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I worked on this for quite some time now.

Comment: This code is way more complicated than it needs to be :/

Comment: "I am not very smart."  Don't confuse lack of experience with lack of intelligence, or be worried that *we'll* confuse them and so feel you have to apologize beforehand for not understanding something.  Everyone was a beginner once, and people aren't born knowing Python.  Not yet, anyway..

Comment: ++1! to @DSM's comment .. people seem to forget this all too often (and frequently around here)

Comment: Thank you for that comment, DSM. Very nice of you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be over-thinking the process a bit. The logic doesn't need to really be split up into case tests like that. The part you have right so far is the total counter, but you should only need to loop over each value in the list. Not do a conditional while, with if..else

Normally I wouldn't just give an answer, but I feel its more beneficial for you to see working code than to try and go through the extra and unnecessary cruft you have so far.

```
def count(l):
    total = 0
    result = []
    for val in l:
        total += val
        result.append(total)
    return result
```

We still use the total counter. And we create an empty list for our results. But all we have to do is loop over each item in the list, add to the total, and append the new value each time. There are no conditionals and you don't have to worry about when a `while` is going to break. It's consistant that you will loop over each item in your original list.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! It makes a lot of sense! I am reading the book Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist
And I have learned all those things to far. Thanks so much once again! You were really very helpful!

Comment: @LukeD: No prob! I figured this was really close to the terminology you have probably been introduced to thus far. Good luck! Let me know if you need any more clarifications on this.

Comment: I will sir. Thanks once again, you were really very helpful. I had to think about the question in a different way, as you have done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are adding the current index with the last one and overriding "total"

```
total = list1[x] + list1[x -1]
```

I guess you want something like this, it will return 31 for the list below.

```
def count(list1):
     x = 0
     total = 0
     while x < len(list1):
         total += list[x]
         print total
         x = x + 1
     return total

list = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
print count(list)
```

Comment: You have identified an underlying problem in the code in the question. However your function returns the sum of the contents of the list, not a new list with the cumulative sums as requested in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach can be

```
>>> given_list = [1, 4, 5, 8]
>>> output_list = [sum(given_list[:num]) for num in range(len(given_list)+1)]
>>> output_list
[0, 1, 5, 10, 18]
>>> output_list[1:]
[1, 5, 10, 18]
>>>
```

See if this works for different kind of list. I leave that for you.

Comment: This is way way way complex for a beginner and and can't image the OP will get it.

Comment: I am ashamed to have attempted the solution this way.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, pyfunc. It is a bit too complicated for me, but thank you for your help. If I were smarter, I'm sure i would understand better!

Comment: @LukeD: There are a lot of really fun ways to compute stuff in less code. You will come across list comprehensions eventually.

Comment: @LukeD: And it is not about being smart at all. It is about learning, persistence and hard work. I guess we all can attempt that. With a bit of help from SO, learning can become enjoyble

Comment: Nothing wrong with presenting this solution as an alternative approach, though perhaps the term "simple" wasn't the optimal word to describe it in this context of OP's question :) .. still certainly Pythonic though.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing exactly what you want to be doing with `total`.

What you're setting `total` to is `list[x] + list[x+1]`. You really want it to be the sum of *all* previous elements and the current element.

Replace `total = list1[x] + list1[x-1]` with `total += list1[x]`.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I tried but it does not work. But it definitively helped, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
def count(list1):
     total = 0
     old = 0
     for position, x in enumerate(list1):
         total = x + old
         old = x
         print total
     return


count([1,1,2,3,5,8,13])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write this function. It's placed in the itertools module:

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([1,2,3]))
[1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: I think an explanation to go along with this terse code would be helpful

Comment: @Levon the name of the function (accumulate) is self-explanatory. And as it's a generator, I called `list` on it

Comment: Yes, *I* know that .. given OP's problems I thought it would have been helpful to provide some minimal (e.g., 1 line) explanation to them - that's all :) Not everyone is comfortable with our "pythonic" ways ...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, one-liner, but definitely working ( http://ideone.com/qtwh7), even though multi-line solutions are clearer on what really happens here:

```
data = [3, 7, 22, -3, 5, -23, 16]

result = reduce(lambda a, b: a+[a[-1]+b], data, [0])[1:]

print result
```

Comment: This can be done without the concatenation: `reduce(lambda r, x: r.append(r[-1] + x) or r, data, [0])[1:]` or even without the indexing `reduce(lambda (res, sum), x: (res.append(sum + x) or res, sum + x), data, ([], 0))[0]`

Comment: my first (second) variant with `len(data) == 1000` is 7(6) times faster, and more memory efficient :)

Comment: @astynax: You may be right, but it looks strange to me ;) And what order of magnitude is it, 7x or 76x faster? ;) You can try to use `map()` in similar manner, though. And it may (should?) be even faster.

Comment: first - 7 times faster, second - 6 times faster. With len(data) == 10000: first - 45 times faster, second - 35 :)

Answer (score 0):

I did the same exercise, and what follows is my solution. It uses only the basic `append` list method and the *slice* list operator.

```
def accum(list):
    """Sequential accumulation of the original list"""
    result = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        result.append(sum(list[:i+1]))
    return result
```