# Writing to a file in a for loop only writes the last value

Tags: python

```
text_file = open("new.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
        var1, var2 = line.split(",");
        myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
        myfile.writelines(var1)
        myfile.close()

text_file.close()
```

I have 10 lines of text in new.txt like `Adam:8154`,
`George:5234`, and so on. Now I want a text file which contains only the names. `xyz.txt` must contain `Adam`, `George`, and so on. The above code leaves me with the 10th name only.

How to have all the 10 names in a single text file?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That is because you are opening , writing and closing the file 10 times inside your for loop. Opening a file in `w` mode erases whatever was in the file previously, so every time you open the file, the contents written to it in previous iterations get erased.

```
myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
myfile.writelines(var1)
myfile.close()
```

You should open and close your file outside for loop.

```
myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
    var1, var2 = line.split(",");
    myfile.write("%s\n" % var1)
    
myfile.close()
text_file.close()
```

You should also notice to **use write** and **not writelines**.

`writelines` writes a list of lines to your file.

Also you should check out the answers posted by folks here that uses `with` statement. That is the elegant way to do file read/write operations in Python

Comment: Or use `with` before the loop.

Comment: it didn't make any change to the result

Comment: @user1481274: I think you are using writelines

Comment: Won't you need the `'\n'` with your `myfile.write(var1)` statement?

Comment: @Levon: You are correct. I was not focusing on how but what he got wrong in his solution. file opening inside loop and incorrect usage of writeline. In fact usage of with is more elegant but that is another jump in understanding and did mention since solution was already provided for that :)

Comment: Good point about taking OP's level/needs into account, sometimes we jump to more "pythonic" solutions quickly and don't spend enough time analysing/explaining the problem that brought up the question in the first place.

Comment: @Levon: I learned it the hard way. See my answer here. It was a shame. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175022/can-you-help-me-with-this-python-exercise/11175077#11175077

Comment: ha ha .. yes, I remember that, not sure I'd say it was a shame, but a learning moment perhaps :) .. I assume you also saw my comment at the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 29):

The main problem was that you were opening/closing files repeatedly inside your loop.

Try this approach:

```
with open('new.txt') as text_file, open('xyz.txt', 'w') as myfile:  
    for line in text_file:
        var1, var2 = line.split(",");
        myfile.write(var1+'\n')
```

We open both files at once and because we are using `with` they will be *automatically* closed when we are done (or an exception occurs). Previously your output file  was repeatedly openend inside your loop.

We are also processing the file line-by-line, rather than reading *all* of it into memory at once (which can be a problem when you deal with really big files).

Note that `write()` doesn't append a newline (`'\n'`) so you'll have to do that yourself if you need it (I replaced your `writelines()` with `write()` as you are writing a single item, not a list of items).

When opening a file for `r`read, the `'r'` is optional since it's the default mode.

Answer (score 14):

It's preferable to use context managers to close the files automatically

```
with open("new.txt", "r"), open('xyz.txt', 'w') as textfile, myfile:
    for line in textfile:
        var1, var2 = line.split(",");
        myfile.write(var1)
```

Comment: I knew you could open multiple files with `with` (I do the same above) but I didn't know this format with the file variables at the end .. learned something new, neat.

Comment: shouldn't be indeented for under with?

Comment: @andilabs, Thanks. Sure should. Better late than never :)