# How to use for loop in the write method?

Tags: python

The program is supposed to read a given file, count the occurrence of each word with a dictionary, then create a file called report.txt and output the list of words and their frequencies

```
infile = open('text file.txt','r')

dictionary = {}
# count words' frequency
for i in range(1,14):
    temp = infile.readline().strip().split()
    for item in temp:
        if dictionary.has_key(item) == False:
            dictionary[item] = 1
        elif dictionary.has_key:
            temp2 =  dictionary.get(item)
            dictionary[item] = temp2 + 1


infile.close()

outfile = open('report.txt','w')
outfile.write( for words in dictionary:
                   print '%15s :' %words, dictionary[words])
```

everything works at the counting part, but
just right at the last part of writing the output, I realize I can't put a for loop in the write method

Comment: Why not putting write inside the `for` for a change? =D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198718/writing-to-a-file-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `write` *inside* the `for` loop:

```
for words in dictionary:
    outfile.write('%15s : %s\n' % (words, dictionary[words]))
```

Alternatively you can use a comprehension, but they're a bit ninja and can be harder to read:

```
outfile.write('\n'.join(['%15s : %s' % key_value for key_value in dictionary.items()]))
```

Comment: When i directly print it on the shell, it prints each word and their frequency in one line, then next word in another line. But when I write it in the file, I realize they all jammed together into the same line. How do I fix this?

Comment: @MandyQuan, I've edited my answer to include `\n` at the end of the string, which is a newline character and ensures the next word will be on a new line

Answer (score 1):

As has been said already in the accepted answer, you need the `write` inside the `for` loop. However, when using files it is also good practice to perform your actions within a `with` context as this will automatically handle the closing of the file. e.g.

```
with open('report.txt','w') as outfile: 
    for words in dictionary:
        outfile.write('%15s : %s\n' % (words, dictionary[words]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several deficiencies:

- You don't use *has_key* and you don't compare to *True* / *False* directly - it is redundant and bad style (in any language)

  `if dictionary.has_key(item) == False:`

should be

```
`if not item in dictionary`
```

It is worth mentioning that using positive test first will be more efficient - because you'll probably have more than 1 occurrence of most words in the file

- *dictionary.has_key* returns a reference to *has_key* method - which in boolean equivalent is True (your code accidentally works, because regardless of the 1st conditions second is always True). Simple *else* would be enough
- The last 2 statements in the condition may be just rewritten as

  `dictionary[item] += 1`

That said, you may use collections.Counter to count words

```
dictionary = Counter()
for lines in source_file:
    dictionary.update(line.split())
```

(BTW, **strip** before **split** is redundant)