# Python does not write to a file when running in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, file-handling

I have a Python file `file1.py` with the following code lines:

```
uname="auto1@mailnesia.com"
pwd="abcdef"
```

I want to replace and change the `uname` to *"auto2mailnesia.com"*, then to *"auto3@mailnesia.com"* and so on and then use the updated `uname` in another file.
Consider a scenario where I want to update `uname` from *auto1* to *auto3*.

I have another Python file `file2.py` with the below code lines:

```
from xxx.xxx import file1

for i in range(0,1):
    currentuser = (uname[uname.index('auto') + 4:uname.index('@')])
    newuser = str(int(currentuser) + 1)
    newusername = uname.replace(currentuser, newuser)
    print(uname)
    print(currentuser)
    print(newusername)
    print(newuser)

    with open(testdataFileName, 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub(uname, newusername, text)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
```

When I run *file2.py* in a loop of 1, then the `uname` gets correctly updated in `file1.py`

Output is as follows:

```
auto1@mailnesia.com
1
auto2@mailnesia.com
2
```

But, when I run `file2.py` in a loop of say 3 then the `uname` gets updated in `file1.py` only once.

Output is as follows:

```
test_auto1@mailnesia.com
1
test_auto2@mailnesia.com
2
test_auto1@mailnesia.com
1
test_auto2@mailnesia.com
2
test_auto1@mailnesia.com
1
test_auto2@mailnesia.com
2
```

I do not understand why `uname` is being updated only once in `file1.py` while running in a loop.

Can someone please give an explanation for this?

Also, if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to a file in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198718/writing-to-a-file-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: What are the values that you actually `print`? Now, look at the code. Why should those values get updated by the file contents? You changed the contents of the file, but why should that matter?

Comment: Anyway, if you want to verify that the file contents changed, the most accurate way to do that is to actually examine the file, for example by opening it in a text editor.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to run file2.py and it reads file1.py. Then convert the value in `file1.py` where `uname="auto1@mailnesia.com"` to `uname="auto2@mailnesia.com"`. If you run it multiple times, I assume you want it to create new sets of uname & pwd pairs where the username keeps incrementing from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 to .... as many times you run. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Or do you want to change the file1.py contents from `uname="auto1@mailnesia.com"` to `uname="auto2@mailnesia.com"`the first run, then change it from 2 to 3 for the next run and so on?

Comment: Cause you are not changing the content in your original file, it is not up to date.  if you make the changes in the file1 programmatically it will work as expected.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : i am importing the contents of file1.py into file2.py
Then I am reading the contents of file1.py and changing those values and writing it back to file1.py
In the next iteration, i am again doing the same

I also manually examined the file after the execution, and the uname in file1.py is updated only once, say from auto1@mailnesia.com to auto2@mailnesia.com,
even though i run it in a loop of n, where n>1

Comment: If you are trying to change one *source .py file* on the fly and have the changes affect your already running program, you should definitely not expect that to work, and if you did somehow get it to work you should expect to have nightmares debugging it. But the reason you are writing the same thing to the file every time is because nothing in your program causes the value of `uname` to change. You are not processing the current file contents each time through the loop; you are re-processing whatever was in `uname` to start with.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : i am actual changing the value of uname in file2.py and storing it in a new variable called newusername
then i am replacing uname(file1.py) by newusername(file2.py) by this line
text = re.sub(uname, newusername, text)

Comment: @JoeFerndz : Your second understanding is correct.
I want to change the file1.py contents from uname="auto1@mailnesia.com" to uname="auto2@mailnesia.com"the first run, then change it from 2 to 3 for the next run and so on.

Comment: @IqbalMohammadRhidwan : I am indeed trying to make the changes in the file1 programmatically, by the below lines 
`with open(testdataFileName, 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = re.sub(uname, newusername, text)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)`

Comment: @FuzeTest, I have posted my answer based on your response. See if this helps you get the desired result. If not, happy to work with you to get it corrected.

Comment: `re.sub(uname, newusername, text)` *does not cause `uname` to change*. I am not talking about replacing text in the file that matches the text in `uname`. I am talking about changing the text that `uname` refers to.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Im sorry if I wasn't clear before.
I am using re.sub to replace uname with newusername and then stroring this in a variable called text
`text = re.sub(uname, newusername, text)`
then i am writing this variable text to my file1.py
`f.seek(0)`
`f.write(text)`

now after f.write(text) gets executed, file1.py should have the new username, but that happen when running in a loop
If you could please just run my code and have a look at the output, it would help
thanks

Comment: Yes; you're storing it in `text`. What happens the next time through the `for` loop? The first thing that happens is `currentuser = (uname[uname.index('auto') + 4:uname.index('@')])`. But `uname` has the same value now that it did before, therefore `currentuser` will get the same value that it did last time, and so on. When you open the file this time around you will read the text again, but then attempt to replace the *same* `uname` with the *same* `newusername`. This is why the `uname` only gets updated once, as you complained: because nothing in the loop changes the value *of `uname`*.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `uname` remains the same through every iteration (no matter what `i` is). It's not updated at the end of each iteration of the loop. Instead, I recommend keeping variables `currentusername` and `currentuser` so that the last username and index (or ID) can be preserved and therefore accessed. These will be initialized *before* the loop begins, and updated before the start of each next iteration.

```py
import re
uname="auto1@mailnesia.com"
pwd="abcdef"

# initialize
currentusername = uname
currentuser = (uname[uname.index('auto') + 4:uname.index('@')])

for i in range(0,4):
    print('\niteration ' + str(i))
    newuser = str(int(currentuser) + 1)
    newusername = currentusername.replace(currentuser, newuser)
    print("uname=" + uname)
    print("currentuser=" + currentuser)
    print("newusername=" + newusername)
    print("newuser=" + newuser)

    with open('somefile.dat', 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub(currentusername, newusername, text)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)

    # update for next iteration
    currentuser = newuser
    currentusername = newusername
```

Output:

```
iteration 0
currentusername=auto1@mailnesia.com
currentuser=1
newusername=auto2@mailnesia.com
newuser=2

iteration 1
currentusername=auto2@mailnesia.com
currentuser=2
newusername=auto3@mailnesia.com
newuser=3

iteration 2
currentusername=auto3@mailnesia.com
currentuser=3
newusername=auto4@mailnesia.com
newuser=4

iteration 3
currentusername=auto4@mailnesia.com
currentuser=4
newusername=auto5@mailnesia.com
newuser=5
```

At the end, `somefile.dat` would include `auto5@mailnesia.com`.

Comment: I am changing the value of uname and storing the new changed value in newusername
Then i am replacing uname in file1 by newusername by the below lines
`
    with open(testdataFileName, 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub(uname, newusername, text)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
`

Comment: I ran your code and getting the following output
`iteration 0  
uname=test_auto1@mailnesia.com  
currentuser=1  
newusername=test_auto2@mailnesia.com  
newuser=2  

iteration 1  
uname=test_auto1@mailnesia.com  
currentuser=2  
newusername=test_auto3@mailnesia.com  
newuser=3  

iteration 2  
uname=test_auto1@mailnesia.com  
currentuser=3  
newusername=test_auto4@mailnesia.com  
newuser=4`


As you can see above, the uname is the same in each iteration, then how come currentuser changes each time, because as far as i understand, currentuser is calculated from uname

Comment: It's calculated from uname originally but then updated in the loop near the bottom. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have a lot of answers already. I thought I will simplify your code a bit. You need to read only the first line.

```
with open('your_filename.txt', 'r+') as f: #update your_filename with your filename
    text = f.readline()
    print ('previous value in file :', text)
    cuser = int(text[11:text.index('@')]) + 1
    text = text[:11]+str(cuser)+text[text.index('@'):]
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    print ('new value in file : ', text)
```

The output each time you run changes. My first run gave me:

```
previous value in file : uname="auto1@mailnesia.com"

new value in file :  uname="auto2@mailnesia.com"
```

The contents in the file shows as:

```
uname="auto2@mailnesia.com"
pwd="abcdef"
```

My 4th run gave me:

```
previous value in file : uname="auto3@mailnesia.com"

new value in file :  uname="auto4@mailnesia.com"
```

The contents in the file shows as:

```
uname="auto4@mailnesia.com"
pwd="abcdef"
```

As you can see, the file keeps getting updated every time i run the code. I am not sure why you need to loop it a few times. Are you trying to change the value in the file a few times for each run?

I am not sure if you really need a loop. I updated my code to create a loop and it still worked. Here's the updated code. I just used a simple `for loop`

```
for i in range(4):

    with open('xyz.txt', 'r+') as f: #update your_filename with your filename

        text = f.readline()

        print ('previous value in file :', text)

        cuser = int(text[11:text.index('@')]) + 1
        text = text[:11]+str(cuser)+text[text.index('@'):]

        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)

        print ('new value in file : ', text)
```

Here's the output I got:

```
previous value in file : uname="auto4@mailnesia.com"

new value in file :  uname="auto5@mailnesia.com"

previous value in file : uname="auto5@mailnesia.com"

new value in file :  uname="auto6@mailnesia.com"

previous value in file : uname="auto6@mailnesia.com"

new value in file :  uname="auto7@mailnesia.com"

previous value in file : uname="auto7@mailnesia.com"

new value in file :  uname="auto8@mailnesia.com"
```

The value in the file is:

```
uname="auto8@mailnesia.com"
pwd="abcdef"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation
Your code works great
I am running this in a loop since I need to test logins for say suppose 10 users, from auto1 to auto 10 (in future this can go on to 100 or 1000 users)
and i do not want to have 10 different uname stored in file1.py
i am reading uname from file1.py and then passing it as a parameter to login function

Your code will read and change the first line from file1.py
Suppose i have uname on line1, pswd on line2, phone number on line3, employee id on line 4 and i only want to change line1,3,4, not the pswd. How to do that

Comment: In that case, you will have to read the file in a loop. and change the information on each line. `for f1 in f:` will help you read each line. You can check the contents of each line and make the changes.

Comment: If it solved your question, you can flag my response as answered. Also, if you want to update your question with the new source file, I can edit the response with the code to solve for it.