# Using 'For Loop' to write data to a file

Tags: python, for-loop, file-writing

I am trying to use 'for loop' to write to a file in python dynamically, but I do not know how to calculate to write dynamically. I would appreciate if I get some help on this.

```
   def earnings(name, age, salary):
        AnnualRate = 0.05
        outFile = open('yearly_earnings.txt', 'w')
        outFile.write('Prepared by: Amornchot Singh')
        outFile.write('Age Salary Total')

        n = 26
        for n in range(66):


        ageLimit = 65
        i = 26
        totalEarned = 0
        for i in range(ageLimit+1):
            totalEarned += salary * (1+AnnualRate)

        print('summary for ' +  name)
        print('Starting salary at age ' + age + ' was ' + salary)
        print('Salary increases were 5.0% per year')
        print('Total accumulated earnings by age 65 is {:,.2f}'.format(totalEarned))

        print("To view yearly data go to 'yearly_earnings.txt'")
        print("'Thank you for using the earnings() function.'")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to a file in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198718/writing-to-a-file-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all remove all redundant lines of code
2. Call the function
3. Don't forget to close the file after writing something, otherwise it
   will not save the data in your file
4. Python don't allow to add integer with string so convert the integer
   into str before concatenating

```
print('Starting salary at age ' + str(age) + ' was ' + str(salary))
```

**Here is full code**

```
def earnings(name, age, salary):
    AnnualRate = 0.05
    outFile = open('yearly_earnings.txt', 'w')
    outFile.write('Prepared by: Amornchot Singh')
    outFile.write('Age Salary Total')

    ageLimit = 65
    i = 26
    totalEarned = 0
    for i in range(ageLimit+1):
        totalEarned += salary * (1+AnnualRate)
    outFile.close()
    print('summary for ' +  name)
    print('Starting salary at age ' + str(age) + ' was ' + str(salary))
    print('Salary increases were 5.0% per year')
    print('Total accumulated earnings by age 65 is {:,.2f}'.format(totalEarned))

    print("To view yearly data go to 'yearly_earnings.txt'")
    print("'Thank you for using the earnings() function.'")
earnings("Tariq", 20, 500000)
```