# code that opens a files, uses a loop to get numbers form user and writes the numbers to the file, then closes the file

Tags: python, file, while-loop

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Write code that does the following: opens an output file with the filename number_list.txt, uses a loop to get numbers from the user, and writes the numbers to the file, then closes the file.

Here's what I have:

```py
while True:
    num = int(input("enter a number, to stop enter 0"))
    myflie = open("number_list.txt", "w")
    myflie.write(str(num))
    if num == 0:
        break
    myflie.close()
```

The code doesn't give me any errors, but when I check the file, only one number gets written to it.

Comment: Opening a file in `"w"` mode erases it, so you're erasing it (deleting its contents) on each iteration. Also, why are re-opening the file on each iteration anyway?

Comment: Why are you not using `with open() as f` format? That itself handles `close` method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a cs freshman, I'm still learning

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. p.s. I'm a Senior Software Engineer. I'm still learning. It never stops.

Comment: I suggest you google for and read the documentation for `open()` to understand how it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to a file in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198718/writing-to-a-file-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Please enter a title that summarizes the problem you are asking about. [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use `a` to write to a file without deleting the contents first, also move the check before the write operation if you don't want '0' to be written as well.

```
while True:
    num = int(input("enter a number, to stop enter 0"))
    if num == 0:
        break

    with open('number_list.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(num))

    # if you want it like this
    # f = open('number_list.txt', 'a')
    # f.write(str(num))
    # f.close()
```

Comment: Alternatively, open the file once outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The mode `"w"` overwrites the contents of the file whenever you write to it. It seems as if you want to append to it, and so, use the mode `"a"`. Also, do file operations using with the `with` statement. Even if the writing process throws an exception, the file will surely close.

```py
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number, to stop enter 0:"))
    if num == 0: break
    
    with open('number_list.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(num))
```

---

If you think having a file operation for every run of the loop is too much, you can append the inputs in a list and do a `writelines` after the user breaks out of the loop.

```py
nums = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number, to stop enter 0:"))
    if num == 0:
        break
    else:
        nums.append(num)

with open('number_list.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writelines(nums)
```